# Is my proof for the existence of a Bernstein set correct?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, set-theory

*I have created the following proof for the existence of a Bernstein set in $\mathbb{R}$. However, I am not quite sure whether it is correct.*

We know that:
$\vert \mathbb{R} \vert = 2^{\omega} = \omega^{\omega} = \vert \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \vert$
(since $2^{\omega} \leq \omega^{\omega} \leq (2^{\omega})^{\omega} = 2^{\omega \cdot \omega} = 2^{\omega}$).

Then, we define a set $\mathcal{P}$ as $\mathcal{P} = \{P\subseteq \mathbb{R} \ \vert \ P \ \text{non-empty and perfect}\}$.

We already proved in the lecture that $\vert \mathcal{P} \vert = 2^{\omega}$.
Therefore, we know that $\vert \mathcal{P} \times \{0,1\} \vert = 2^\omega \cdot 2 = 2^\omega$.

Further, Cantor proved that $\vert P \vert = 2^\omega$.

Now, we can define a bijective function $p\colon \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathcal{P} \times \{0,1\}$, where $p(f) = (P_f,i_f)$ for $f\in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$.

Let $<$ be a well-order on $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ of minimal length and let $<_x$ be the well-order on $\mathbb{R}$ that is induced by the bijection $h\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$.

With this, we can define by recursion over $\langle \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N},<\rangle$:

$x_f :=$ "The $<_x$-smallest $x\in P_f$ with $x\neq x_g$ $\forall \ g<f$".

If we now choose a set $B$ as $B := \{x_f \ \vert \ f\in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}, i_f = 0\}$, then $B$ is by construction a Bernstein set.

*Thank you for your help!*

Comment: My quirky complaint is the (common) misuse of $\omega$ for $\aleph_0$.  We know $\omega$ is an ordinal, but $\aleph_0$ is a cardinal.  So of course logically $2^\omega$ should be computed as ordinal exponentiation...

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you for your correction! I actually didn't know that since my professor said that $\omega$ and $\aleph_0$ are basically the same

Comment: You have implicitly assumed that $|P_f|=2^{\aleph_0}$ so that $P_f\not\subseteq \{x_g:g<f\}.$ This would fail if there existed a perfect set $S$ with $|S|< 2^{\aleph_0}. $ However, there isn't one. Every perfect set (& any uncountable closed subset of $\Bbb R)$ does have cardinal $2^{\aleph_0}.$ Other than this missing detail, it's fine.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thank you! I will add that part of the proof